# Is there a sharing library for programmed drums for musicians to play along with that are like the real song they are playing?

Tags: drums

I'm in a hobby basement band we use a drum machine, Dr. Boss. We play Rock music. We program the drums to sound as close as possible to whatever song we are playing which is very tedious. Does anyone know if there is a sharing library of drums that we can borrow. We could share ours too, ours are on floppy discs. Know where we could purchase drum tracks for our machine?

Comment: I'm guessing that you won't find many people in this century that will be excited about trading floppy disks in the mail. :)

Comment: What is the model number on your machine?

Comment: Have you thought about actually getting a drummer?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can't advice a concrete library for a specific hardware you're specified there, but I can advice you next thing:

There's a lot of sites on the internet which have tabulatures in Guitar Pro or power tab format. If you can a bring a PC to your rehearsal place, and connect it to a speakers, your problem would be solved.

For example, you can look at the site http://ultimate-guitar.com, which have tabs in guitar pro format for almost every widely (and not really widely) known songs. Those tabulatures often (in 90 of cases) contain a drum track. You can buy needed software, open that tab, select to play only a drum track, turn on the RSE (realistic sound engine), and probably you'll receive a quite good drum backing track.

Or, also, you can export that drum track in midi format to FL studio or some other sequencer and run it with  plugin like EZDrummer (for example) or some other wave table plugin which have real drum sounds. So that option also would give you a quite well drummer sound too.

Comment: As I said, he can extract a drum track from the tab, export it to a midi, then import it into a FL studio, run it in Ez Drummer and a receive a quite good sound.